# Scrapy: How to initialize item with None?

Tags: scrapy

For example, the item in scrapy is:

```
class CrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):

    name = scrapy.Field()

    country = scrapy.Field()

    title = scrapy.Field()

    subject = scrapy.Field()

    ......
item = CrawlerItem()
```

How could I initialize all of the fields value of item with None?

I could do this with:

```
item['name'] = None
item['country'] = None
...
```

But the problem is, there're far two many fields. Are there any methods that could do:? `item.set_all(None)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to iterate through `self.fields` in the items class

```
class CrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):

    name = scrapy.Field()
    country = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    subject = scrapy.Field()

    def set_all(self, value):
        for keys, _ in self.fields.items():
            self[keys] = value
```

And then in your code you can call

```
item = CrawlerItem()
item.set_all(None)
print(item)
```

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks!